# How to resolve "malloc(): memory corruption" in C with MPI

Tags: c, memory, malloc, mpi, corruption

I use MPI in C and I've an array of double so stated:

```
double *x = NULL;
```

I pass this array as a double pointer to a function and i try to execute a malloc in this way:

```
*x = (double*) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
```

where `n` is a integer. The compilation it's ok but the execution return this error:

```
malloc(): memory corruption
main: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 3842 RUNNING AT DESKTOP
=   EXIT CODE: 134
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Aborted (signal 6)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 134
```

What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you dereferencing ```x```?

Comment: For a security reason but it isn't the problem because, if I remove it, it's the same.

Comment: It's useful because permits to avoid to read a part of memory not allocated.

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question. Try using http://valgrind.org/

Comment: Please show at least the function prototype and invocation.

Comment: note this malloc might be legit, but crashes as a consequence of some previous memory corruption. Tools such as valgrind can help you. If not, share a [mcve] so you can get help.

Answer (score 2):

`*x = (double*) malloc(n * sizeof(double));`

`*x` dereferences `x`, so it gets the value `x` points to (a `double`). `*x` is NULL, in C dereferencing a NULL pointer is undefined behaviour.

`(double*) malloc` returns a pointer of type double (a `double*`)

So you are saying `double *` == `double`, hence crash.

Modify your code to `x = (double*) malloc(n * sizeof(double));`, so now `x` points to an allocated area of memory with size of `n * sizeof(double)`

Actually, I am surprised that your compiler is not warning you about that.

Comment: I've already tried but this returns "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]" during the compilation.

Comment: Can you add your attempt to the question?

Comment: i guess you got mislead by the "double pointer" terminology. You might have understood "pass `x` that has type `double *`", when the OP could have meant "pass `&x` that has type `double **`". Anyway, that's why an OP should always post a [mcve] instead of discussing in what was done in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use malloc in the below format may be it may help, `if((*x = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)))==NULL) {printf("\n memory allocation error")};`, By this you will get know whether there is a problem in memory allocation or your program, and try to use the above format.

Comment: I've just tried but the console prints the same error.

Comment: Try these two `1.x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n)` where n is the number of doubles you want. `2.x = calloc(n,sizeof(double))`